# default_random_engine’ does not name a type

Tags: c++, unix, makefile

I am using a makefile and then make to link and compile the files I'm using

In one project in directory `ws/arthur/MS/inc/PQ`, I have the file `abc.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

class abc
{
    private:
        default_random_engine generator;
};

#endif
```

and in directory `ws/arthur/abc/inc/abc`, I have the file `hit.h`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <abc/hit.h>

class hit
{
    private:
         std::vector<int> dictionary;
    public:
};
```

The files in `abc` link and compile with no problems

I then copied and pasted all the files from `abc` in `hit`

But when I compile and link `abc` using `make`, I get the error `ws/arthur/abc/inc/abc.h: error: ‘default_random_engine’ does not name a type`

What is going on?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're missing the std:: prefix on default_random_engine
i.e.

```
std::default_random_engine generator;
```

Hope that helps. If you still get the error after adding that, please edit your post.

Comment: Yes, I still got the same error even when adding the `std::`. Also, there was no problem with `default_random_engine generator` in the MS Project. I only got that error in the SM project